# Normalized linear program

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

consider a linear program in standard form:

$min \; cx$

$Ax = b$

$x \ge 0$

Let suppose that the optimal solution is $[x_1,x_2,x_3]$ where $x_i \ge 0$.  Is it possible reformulate the linear program into a new one where the solution is the normalized solution of the previous one (i.e $[\frac{x_1}{\sum x_i},\frac{x_2}{\sum x_i},\frac{x_3}{\sum x_i}]$)?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding something but can't you just change $A$ to $(\sum x_i) \cdot A$?

Comment: But I do not know the solution, in this example we suppose to know it, generally it miss. I wanna a general procedure to reformulate the linear program in another linear program with the same solution but normalized.

Comment: I get the same solution as Dániel G.

Comment: Maybe I do not understand. You say to write a program like this :  $\sum x_i A = b$ and the rest equal to the previous one?

Comment: @G.. yes just multiply the matrix $A$ by the positive constant $\sum x_i$.

Comment: But in order to have a linear program you need a form like this $Ax =b$  now since the $x_i $ are unknown you have something like this $\sum x_i \cdot A x = b $ and this is not linear.

Comment: I am pretty sure Dániel suggested to solve the problem as-is, then take the optimal solution to rescale $A$. I doubt there is a faster way. *Maybe* you can solve it as a single problem, but that problem will have extra variables and constraints and will not be as fast as what Dániel proposed. I can try working it out as an answer if you are still interested.

Comment: I understand the Daniel and pH answer, but I'm interesting in a procedure without knowing the solution. For example something like you take $Ax = b$ and if you normalize the equations dividind every rows by $b$ then  the solution is the normalized solution of the original solution. Probably this is not True, I do not know, I thought that maybe someone know a trick.

Comment: Ah ok, if this trick does not exist there is nothing to do

Comment: Did you appreciate my solution? You can mark this question as answered if that's the case.

Answer (score 1):

This formulation solves the normalized problem as long as $x=0$ is not the optimal solution to the original problem:

$$\min_{x,y} \left\{ c^Tx : Ax=by, e^Tx = 1, x\geq0, y\geq0 \right\}$$

Comment: Hi, sorry for delay, I'm glad to check your answer, but I do not understand why this work fine. How this linear program could assure the linear constraints if I multiply b with a y variable? If I can manipulate b with decision variables y I loose the utility of constraints.

Comment: @G.. in your question you scale down $x$, so the scaled $x$ does not satisfy $Ax=b$ either (but it satisfies $Ax=by$ with $y=1/\sum x_i$)